# .NET's Match.Result in javascript

Tags: javascript, .net, regex

Is there an equivalent to Match.Result from .NET in javascript so that using a replace function, one can still use the convenient substitutions for perhaps part of the logic?

Or does one need to provide a custom yet simple function like the following which seems to work in all cases?

```
RegExp.matchResult = function (subexp, offset, str, matches) {
    return subexp.replace(/\$(\$|&|`|\'|[0-9]+)/g, function (m, p) {
        if (p === '$') return '$';
        if (p === '`') return str.slice(0, offset);
        if (p === '\'') return str.slice(offset + matches[0].length);
        if (p === '&' || parseInt(p, 10) <= 0 || parseInt(p, 10) >= matches.length) return matches[0];
        return matches[parseInt(p, 10)];
    });
};
var subexp; //fill in with substitution expression
var replaceFunc = function () {
    return RegExp.matchResult(subexp, arguments[arguments.length - 2], arguments[arguments.length - 1], Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).slice(0, -2));
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function looks nice, but I can think of a different way:

```js
String.prototype.replaceMatch = function(re, replacement, fn) {
  fn = fn || function(p) { return p; };
  return this.replace(re, function(m) {
    var replaced = m.replace(re, replacement);
    var params = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    params.unshift(replaced);
    return fn.apply(this, params);
  });
};

// Some simple example
alert("foo 42 bar 12345 baz".replaceMatch(
  /(\d)(\d*)/g,
  "[$1]($2)",
  function(replaced, m, a, b) {
    return replaced + "<" + a + "," + b + ">";
  }
));
```

**There's a gotcha:** it will only work if the regex can match the result of a match, so it's not applicable to all cases. (I realized this after writing the answer)

And I don't know if it really qualifies as *simpler* than yours though...

Comment: Nice way of thinking about it to use the engine to do the logic: I suppose the var replaced = m.replace(re, replacement); should instead of re just using /.*/ as really it is just to force the whole string to always be the match and if there were lookahead conditions they would not be satisfied on the partial string.  This should fix the gotcha.

Comment: @Gregory, no unfortunately you need the original regex to extract the captured groups for the replacement string (`$1`, `$2` etc)